# Ajax POST to views.py function

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I've spent the better part of my morning going through a couple of tutorials and reading through related questions here and I still can't seem to get this right.  I've created a simplified version of what I need to do just to try to understand how ajax works.  In a nut shell: I want to pass two numbers to a function in views.py.  This simple function will multiply these two numbers and send them back.  Here's what I've done so far:

html:

```
<button type="button" onclick="mathIt()">Send Test Data</button>


{% csrf_token %}
<p id="test"> Test</p> 


<script>

function mathIt() {
  var aNumber = 5;
  var bNumber = 15;
  // alert ("Two numbers: "+aNumber+" and "+bNumber);
  $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/multiply",
      data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
        aNumber: aNumber,
        bNumber: bNumber,
      },
      success: function(data) {
        alert ("Congrats! You sent some data: "+data);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert ("Something went wrong");
      }
  });

  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = result_mult;
}

</script>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^multiply$', 'prof_pages.views.multiply'),
```

multiply is a function defined in views.py of app prof_pages

views.py

```
def product(a1,a2):
    return float(a1 * a2)

def multiply(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        try:
            b1 = request.POST['aNumber']
            b2 = request.POST['bNumber']
        except KeyError:
            return HttpResponse('Error') # Incorrect Post

        result_mult = product(b1,b2)
        return HttpResponse(result_mult)
    else:
        raise Http404
```

when I click on the button the error message displays and I get a 500 Error for the POST method on my console.  And of course the network monitor also shows the 500 error

I'm not entirely sure my url is set-up properly; if it isn't that I'm not sure where else to look.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to open response in new tab, if you are using firefox. Then you will get the django error page. Post the error message.

Comment: A 500 error is a server site error, you should see a traceback on the console if you are in development mode or in the error log (maybe the one of the WSGI implementation) if you have a deployed environment. Also, you are posting to `/multiply` and in `urls.py` you have a trailing slash `r'^multiply/$'`.

Comment: Klaus, I've removed the trailing slash in urls.py, but still getting the same error.  The full line in the traceback looks like this:  [31/Oct/2015 18:54:50] "POST /multiply HTTP/1.1" 500 9939.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further review of the traceback I noticed that the issue generating the 500 error was the multiply function not executing.  This was caused by the data being pulled in as a str type, which I think is the default.  By adding the correct data type, float, to the request.POST calls the issue was resolved.  So my views.py now looks like this:

```
def multiply(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        try:
            b1 = float(request.POST['aNumber'])
            b2 = float(request.POST['bNumber'])
        except KeyError:
            return HttpResponse('Error') # Incorrect Post

        result_mult = b1 * b2
        return HttpResponse(result_mult)
    else:
        raise Http404
```

The other change to my code is in urls.py I noticed that the complete request URL looked like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/multiply
```

so accordingly my urls.py now looks like this:

```
url(r'^profile/multiply$', 'prof_pages.views.multiply'),
```

Thanks to all who responded.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

`aNumber` and `bNumber` are not defined in your view. You mean:

```
        b1 = request.POST['aNumber']
        b2 = request.POST['bNumber']
```